# formValidation (old BootstrapValidator) break my form submit through Ajax even if I change the code to achieve new API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have recently update the old BootstrapValidator to the new 0.6.0 release which is call now [formValidation](http://formvalidation.io/). I have, also, read the docs from the beginning to the end more than once trying to find where the problem is but no success so far so I'll need some help. This are the changes I made to achieve new API compatibility:

**CSS Styles included on the page and order**

```
/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
/components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
/components/bootstrapvalidator/dist/css/formValidation.min.css"
/components/select2/select2.css"
/components/fuelux/dist/css/fuelux.min.css"
/css/select2-bootstrap.css"
```

**Scripts included on the page and order**

```
 /components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
/components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
/components/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js
/components/bootstrapvalidator/dist/js/formValidation.min.js
/components/bootstrapvalidator/dist/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js
/components/bootstrapvalidator/dist/js/language/es_ES.js
/components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js
/js/bootstrap-growl.min.js
/components/select2/select2.min.js
/components/select2/select2_locale_es.js
/components/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js
/components/fuelux/dist/js/fuelux.min.js
/components/bootstrap-filestyle/src/bootstrap-filestyle.js
/bundles/app/js/RPNI/wzInscripcionSolicitud.js
/bundles/app/js/RPNI/wzAgregarProductos.js
```

This is how I'm using the validation plugin:

```
$('#crearSolicitudUsuario')
    .find('[name="solicitudUsuario[tipoRegistro]"]')
    .select2()
    .change(function (e) {
        $('#crearSolicitudUsuario').formValidation('revalidateField', 'solicitudUsuario[tipoRegistro]');
    })
    .end()
    .find('[name="solicitudUsuario[oficinaRegional]"]')
    .change(function (e) {
        $('#crearSolicitudUsuario').formValidation('revalidateField', 'solicitudUsuario[oficinaRegional]');
    })
    .end()
    .formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap', // this should be set by default but just for testing purposes I set here
        excluded: ':disabled',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'fa fa-check',
            invalid: 'fa fa-times',
            validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
        },
        container: 'popover',
        fields: {
            'solicitudUsuario[tipoTramite]': {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Debe escoger una opción',
                        callback: function (value, validator) {
                            var options = validator.getFieldElements('solicitudUsuario[tipoRegistro]').val();
                            return (options != null && options.length >= 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            'solicitudUsuario[oficinaRegional]': {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Debe escoger una opción',
                        callback: function (value, validator) {
                            var options = validator.getFieldElements('solicitudUsuario[oficinaRegional]').val();
                            return (options != null && options.length >= 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(e.target),
            bv = $form.data('formValidation');
        bv.disableSubmitButtons(false);

        console.log("Enter here");

        $.post(Routing.generate('guardarSolicitudRPNI'), $form.serialize(), 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // some code goes here
        }).fail(function () {
            // some code goes here
        });
    });
```

**Issues:**

- `console.log()` is not executed, even if form is valid it returns to the original status (some kind of page reload)
- form is never submitted

What I'm doing wrong? Did I miss something here? Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, was my bad, I miss some changes that causes break the formValidation, here was the changes I made:

```
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'fa fa-check',
        invalid: 'fa fa-times',
        validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
    },
    container: 'popover',
```

for:

```
icon: {
    valid: 'fa fa-check',
    invalid: 'fa fa-times',
    validating: 'fa fa-refresh'
},
err: {
    container: 'popover'
},
```

That's all, issue fixed!